# Enable Youtube embedding only to my own website

Tags: youtube, live-streaming

I'm doing some video coverage and running live in the youtube website, Few other persons are taken my youtube embed code and implemented in their own website. So i planed to restrict the embedding and disabled the option.

Now the problem is it not running on my own website also, if there is any option to run the videos only on own website and restricting the streaming on other websites.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the view count on your public video much, here is what you do:

1. Disable embedding on your public video.
2. Upload a duplicate of your public video.
3. Set the duplicate to *unlisted,* instead of *public.*
4. Enable embedding on the unlisted duplicate video.
5. Embed the unlisted version of the video on your own website, using the direct link. Anyone with a *direct link* to the unlisted video could embed it, but since the video is unlisted, only people who visit the video using the embedded version on your website will even be able to get the direct link to the embeddable version.

Other than this, I don't think there is a practical solution to your question which is available to the masses (though some, say, corporate content providers have apparently been granted such a solution).